# Filter array using custom object property

Tags: ios, ios7

I have an array of objects.Each object has its own properties (name, desc, status). `name` and `desc` are `NSString` and `status` is `BOOL`.

I want to filter this array by status property. Ex: Get all objects with `status == YES`.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: It helps if you provide details of what you have tried.

Comment: @Kumar,  thanks for editing. I'll foresee next time.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try use NSPredictate

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"status = %@", @"YES"];
NSArray *filterArray = [array filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
```

This gives you an array with all object where status is equal YES.

Comment: Thanks, It works and the answer was first.

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
NSPredicate *predicate =[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"status = YES"];
NSArray *filteredArray = [yourArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
```

Comment: why copy other answer?

Comment: this is not a copied answer.

Comment: You may post correct answer, but check if anyone post as like you. then post your answer or give some more description...

Comment: @Ilario This is not a copied answer apparently. See the timestamps, Greg and him posted at the same time. So it might just be a coincidence

Comment: @NSNoob yes, that is what happened.. Coincidence!

Comment: @NSNoob yes, that is what happened.. Coincidence!

Answer (score -1):

Hi you can try this one,

```
NSMutableArray *array =[NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"Apple", @"Animal", @"baby", @"ball", nil];

NSPredicate *aPredicate =
    [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF beginswith[a] 'b'"];
NSArray *beginWithA =
    [array filteredArrayUsingPredicate:aPredicate];

The beginWithA array will have { @"Apple", @"Animal" }.

NSPredicate *bPredicate =
    [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF contains[b] 's'"];
[array filterUsingPredicate:bPredicate];
The array will have { @"baby", @"ball" }
```

Thanks

Comment: this does not answer the question.