# How can I assign element of array to my property?

Tags: ios, objective-c, runtime

I have an array that stores models:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *models;
```

and other properties of type "Model",like:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) Model *mainModel;
@property (nonatomic, strong) Model *adModel;
@property (nonatomic, strong) Model *tradeModel;
@property (nonatomic, strong) Model *tradeOpenModel;
```

I want to assign every element of `models` to property, how can I do this by runtime instead of `self.mainModel = models[0];`

Comment: how a model is identified as main,ad,trade,tradeopen model?

Comment: Why you don't want to use `self.mainModel = models[0]` ?

Comment: just an example, I want to get the model by property instead of `models[0]`.

Comment: Did you mean `[models objectAtIndex:0]`? You should explain you question more clearly.

Comment: If you are able to differentiate model through a property then you don't need these extra properties. Just filter your array whenever you need a specific model by that property.

Comment: how to filter? @MuhammadZohaibEhsan

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21572509/filter-array-using-custom-object-property

Comment: if you have any problem please ask i will try to clearify

Comment: thank you, i will try. @MuhammadZohaibEhsan

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of NSMutableArray use a custom model (lets say allModelList) that will contain the other four models i.e mainModel,adModel,tradeModel,tradeOpenModel as properties. So while parsing you can set these properties and then easily access by

```
allModelList.mainModel
allModelList.adModel
allModelList.tradeModel
allModelList.tradeOpenModel
```

Hope it helps you.

Comment: Let me know if some other help is required :)